# Automation for product purchase in different currencies

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate product purchase and order confirmation functionality. There are 5 currencies for different countries. So price changes for every country depending upon currency and tax rule. I have to verify if tax is calculated properly or not.
I am planning to create separate test case for each currency, and verify something like this in each test case for every currency and tax rule:

```
            //CHECKPOINT - VERIFY SHIPPING PRICE 
            String actualshipingprice1 = OSP.Getshippingvalue().getText();
            Assert.assertEquals(actualshipingprice1, "$0.00");
            System.out.print("Shipping price is $0\n"); 

            //CHECKPOINT -VERIFY TAX PRICE 
            String actualtaxprice = OSP.Gettaxvalue().getText();
            Assert.assertEquals(actualtaxprice, "$0.00");
            System.out.print("TAX price is $0\n"); 

            //CHECKPOINT - Verify Total Price 
            String actualtotalprice = OSP.Gettotalprice().getText();
            Assert.assertEquals(actualtotalprice, "$19.95 USD");
            System.out.print("Total  price is $19.95 USD\n");
```

I wanted to see if is it good way to verify this functionality or there is any other approach I can follow.

Thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking, but you're on the right track keeping multiple currencies separate and never converting them. You should never convert currencies unless it is a record of an associated bank action.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a common interface which is implemented by different currency implementation and then one single test case verifying everything but you change the concrete implementation on the fly by dynamic binding